# BMP Header - MSDN vague, is my endianness wrong?

Tags: c++, header, endianness, bmp

I'm writing a program to create an image for some data from my chemistry lab. We're working on emissions from elements and such, and the data write-up to include examples of what the frequency bands looked like through the spectroscope. I thought it'd be neat to make a program to do it for me, as opposed to colored pencils, so it's all tidy and stuff. Also, I don't have colored pencils.

I'm storing the image data as RGB values in an int array, of length width*height of the image I want, width being 320, height is 50. In the end I'm writing them to file as 24 bit BGR-ordered pixels.

Before I write the data to file, I of course attempt to write the BMP header. MSDN had a chart to show the general ordering of the file sections, which included something about RBGQuads, but in the paragraph explanations didn't describe how to use them. I think they're optional? I find this chart showing what I expected was the only mandatory part of the header:
http://www.fastgraph.com/help/bmp_header_format.html, so I think I'm on the right track there.

So then I get to the endianness, because my files are always "damaged or corrupt" when trying to open with Paint or in the Windows image viewer.

All sources say BMP headers are little endian. I've tried swapping the order of the bytes both ways when I write and the files still can't be opened. Are there other common culprits for home-brewed corrupt files?

Here's where I store my header infos:

```
typedef struct
{
  char type[2];
  unsigned int fsize;
  unsigned short res1;
  unsigned short res2;
  unsigned int data_offset;
} BMPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct
{
  unsigned int sizebytes;
  int  width_pix;
  int  height_pix;                   // negative for top down.
  unsigned short  planes;            // must be 1
  unsigned short  bits_per_pix;
  unsigned int compression;          // zero for BI_RGB (uncompressed)
  unsigned int SizeImage;            // may be set to 0 for BI_RGB images.
  int  pix_per_meter_x;
  int  pix_per_meter_y;
  unsigned int color_used;           // set to 0
  unsigned int color_important;      // set to 0
} BMPINFOHEADER;
```

And of course I write them in that order. -- type is char[] because it has to be the values 'B' 'M' anyway.

First I tried writing them with fwrite():

```
  fwrite ( &header , 1 , 14 , fhandle );
  fwrite ( &headerext , 1 , 40 , fhandle );
```

And then I tried writing them like this:

```
  fputc ( 'B' , fhandle );
  fputc ( 'M' , fhandle );
  fw_little_end ( fhandle , &header.fsize , 4 );
  fw_little_end ( fhandle , &header.res1 , 2);
  fw_little_end ( fhandle , &header.res2 , 2);
  fw_little_end ( fhandle , &header.data_offset , 4);
```

where fw_little_end() looks like this:

```
void fw_little_end ( FILE * fhandle , void * data , int size )
{
  int i;
  char * cdata = data;
  for ( i = size; i > 0; i-- )
  {
    fputc ( *(cdata+i-1) , fhandle );
  }
}
```

It may be that originally it was written to file little endian and that my `fw_()` function is mis-named, but I've also tried it from size-0 and from 0-size just to be sure.

In case it sounds relevant, this is where the data is written:

```
  int shift1 = 256;
  int shift2 = 256*256;
  for ( i = 0; i < img_size; i++)
  {
    fputc ( (unsigned char) (data[i]%256) , fhandle ); // B
    fputc ( (unsigned char) (data[i]/shift1)%256 , fhandle ); // G
    fputc ( (unsigned char) (data[i]/shift2)%256 , fhandle ); // R
  } // theoretically B only needs the typecast, not the %256 but oh well lol.
```

The post is already long, hopefully I've included enough relevant code. I apologize because I know that there is a lot of info out there, it just doesn't make sense to me beyond this. If there's a better idiom for how to do these sorts of things, I'd love to be pointed in the right direction.

And so, I thank you for any and all input.

Comment: The easiest way of solving this is to compare your file to a BMP file created by some other program, like Paint. Make your program match Paint.

Comment: Actually, an easier way is to not write code to write files when that code already exists in the OS. Use the OS-supplied routines for writing out image files. Try using [CImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwea7by5(VS.80).aspx) instead of re-inventing the wheel. (Though doing it yourself can be a fun exercise.)

Comment: Make sure you open the file as "binary"! Also, check that sizeof(BMPFILEHEADER) == 14 and sizeof(BMPINFOHEADER) == 40. If they are not, you may need to make the compiler understand you want different amounts of spacing in your file.

Comment: @RaymondChen Your advice was good. I wish I could make the thing myself but what I did was just made a file in Paint with the same dimensions and color breadth, and copied the first 54 bytes over.

But now there's a different problem. The Visual C++ Express 2008 compiler, or something, seems to be spitting in my file. There were horizontal bands that I tested against, that I don't put in. When read as text they look like this:  
C :\ Wi nd ow s\ Wi nS xS \x 86 _m ic ro so ft .v c9 0. cr t_ 1f c8 b3 b9 a1 e1 8e 3b _9 .0 .3 07 29 .6 16 1_ no ne _5 09 34 f  Àb~  |d~5 7\ MS V... -> What is that?

Comment: @wyattlindsey At this point you have a different question: "Why is unwanted text appearing in my file when I try to write it?"

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a direct answer:

```
/* ======================================================================================== */
BOOL SaveBitmap24(LPCTSTR pszFilename, LPBYTE pPixelColorTriplets, INT nWidth, INT nHeight)
{
    BOOL bState = FALSE;
    // sizes
    INT nOfsetToPixel = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPCOREHEADER);
    INT nPixelSize = nWidth * nHeight * 3;
    INT nFileSize = nOfsetToPixel + nPixelSize;
    // setup bitmap file header --------------
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmFileHeader = { 0 };
    // "BM" signature
    bmFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;
    bmFileHeader.bfOffBits = nOfsetToPixel;
    bmFileHeader.bfSize = nFileSize;
    // setup bitmap info header --------------
    BITMAPCOREHEADER bmCoreHeader = { 0 };
    bmCoreHeader.bcSize = sizeof(BITMAPCOREHEADER);
    bmCoreHeader.bcWidth = nWidth;
    bmCoreHeader.bcHeight = nHeight;
    bmCoreHeader.bcBitCount = 24;
    bmCoreHeader.bcPlanes = 1;
    // write file -----------------------
    FILE *fileBitmap = fopen(pszFilename, _T("wb"));
    if (fileBitmap)
    {   fwrite(&bmFileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, fileBitmap);
        fwrite(&bmCoreHeader, sizeof(bmCoreHeader), 1, fileBitmap);
        fwrite(pPixelColorTriplets, nPixelSize, 1, fileBitmap);
        fclose(fileBitmap);
        bState = TRUE;
    }
    return bState;
}
```